# Does a Google Datastore query plus transaction run slower than just a query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Are Google Datastore queries slower when put into a transaction? Assuming the query is exactly the same, would the run time of a transaction + query be slower than the query not in a transaction?

Does the setup of the transaction add any execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some data from running a single document get 100 times sequentially.

| type | avg | p99 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| transactional | 46ms | 86ms |
| nontransactional | 16ms | 27ms |